# Add non safe font to html signatures

Tags: html, css, email, fonts, signature

I am trying to add a particular non web safe font to a html signature with Helvetica as the back up font. I have tried all different variations of naming the font in the code (HKGrotesk-Regular, HK Grotesk Regular, HKGrotesk etc) but I cannot get it to work in my browser even though the font is installed on my Mac. Note: I know this font won't show in most computers but the client has asked for it.
My question is what do I call the font in the code or is there another reason it is not working?

```
    <table>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="3" style="font-family: 'HKGrotesk-Regular', serif; font-size: 9px; line-height: 12px">
             <span style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 14px">First Name</span><br>
    Job Title
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the font is installed in your computer, the HTML document can not render it to the webpage. To achieve this, you will have to download the web front font. I found a website that has the font - https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/hk-groteks. Once the download is complete, make sure these font files have an extension ".woff". Then you will have to use the following code in the in your main CSS file -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HK Grotesk Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('HK Grotesk Regular'), url('HKGrotesk-Regular.woff') 
    format('woff');
}
```

The above code should go before your table element for this to work.

Regards,
Vijay.